# Renaming any file (only in Nautilus) is taking a lot of time

Tags: nautilus, files, rename

I'm trying to rename files using Nautilus but it's taking a lot of time

[image: screenshot]

Operation gets cancelled if I click on cancel. and for the duration of renaming which is generally around 30 secs I can't even open that file. it's really painful while renaming multiple files. It's just affecting Nautilus, `mv` is fine and it generally happens on the newly created files

**What I've tried?**

I've tried Reinstalling Nautilus

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall nautilus
```

I think it solved the problem for some time, But I again encountered it today

I'm using Ubuntu Gnome 17.04 if that matters

Comment: Does it also take that long if you rename it from the terminal using `mv` or is it just Nautilus? It's probably also interesting on what kind of storage medium and file system the file is located.

Comment: @ByteCommander let me try with `mv` and storage is a 7200rpm Toshiba HDD and file system is Ext4

Comment: If you rename within the same partition, the operation should be 'lightning fast', if you rename alias move from one partition to another one, the file's content must be written to the new partition, which can take time. If it takes time within the same partition, I think there is some [unnecessary?] overhead task going on. I ask the same question as @ByteCommander: What happens if you rename with the `mv` command?

Comment: yup, mv is also taking time

Comment: Is it within the same partition?

Comment: @sudodus sorry `mv` was instant, I messed up the command first time, `mv` is happening instantly, they are within the same directory (let alone partition)

Comment: OK, so we can blame Nautilus, or some tool used by Nautilus. Maybe there is some data-base for quick search that is updated.

Comment: @sudodus definitely, I should just try to reinstall nautilus

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/60528/discussion-between-sudodus-and-sumeet-deshmukh).